# Is geda-utils package not available for 20.04?

Tags: package-management

After upgrading to 20.04 I tried to reinstall 'geda-utils', only to find out that the package is not available:

```
$ sudo apt install geda-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package geda-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'geda-utils' has no installation candidate
```

While other gEDA packages are available and installed.

I have to add that my 'universe' repository is enabled.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "other gEDA packages" are available specifically? I don't see any that have 20.04 releases.

Comment: I have the following packages available and installed, all at ver. 1.8.2-6:

geda, geda-doc, geda-examples, geda-gattrib, geda-gnetlist, geda-gschem, geda-gsymcheck, geda-symbols. Geda-utils should be there but strangely it is not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fork of gEDA available in the ubuntu repositories called lepton-eda which seems to be actively maintained https://github.com/lepton-eda/lepton-eda

`apt install lepton-eda` should work. With it I could open schematics I've created with gEDA's gschem without problems so far. Didn't try any of the others utilities though.

Comment: Hi! I didn't know that, thanks! From what I read, lepton-eda is backwards-compatible with gEDA.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question "is it no longer available" is a simple yes. Along with your output from apt, a quick [search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geda&searchon=names) of packages with the name `geda` reveal no packages in the focal fossa repositories. As for the other packages, I would guess you already had these installed before you upgraded. As for whether it will be in the future or whether the `.deb` files from 18.04 will work, that depends on the package maintainers.

Comment: I see. And how can I contact the package maintainers to fix this, since geda-utils contains essential command-line tools for the suite?

Comment: You can go [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/geda-utils) and look under the "Maintainers" section of the sidebar for ways to contact the maintainers. You also may want to see if you can get the version from 18.04 to install as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I 'll do that ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

Start at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/geda-gaf :

> source package has 1 unsatisfiable build dependency
> 1 binary package has unsatisfiable dependencies
> A new upstream version is available: 1.10.0
> lintian reports 3 errors and 8 warnings
> The package has not entered testing even though the delay is over
> Depends on packages which need a new maintainer
> Multiarch hinter reports 2 issue(s)
> version in VCS is newer than in repository, is it time to upload?
> RM: This package has been requested to be removed.
> AppStream hints: 2 warnings
> Build log checks report 4 warnings
> Standards version of the package is outdated.

You can see that the previous package maintainer is no longer maintaining, so contacting them is unlikely to accomplish much.

A new volunteer --or preferably several new volunteers-- are needed to step up, learn the skills, and take over the work.

Debian and Ubuntu are the product of volunteer efforts like that.

It's too late for 20.04 and 20.10: Packages uploaded after release will NOT be backported unless there are exceptional circumstances (like a critical vulnerability). A new volunteer maintainer(s) will need to hustle to get the package buildable for 21.04 before Debian import freeze in a few months.

Comment: This probably would be the accepted answer aside from the fact mine was a bit sooner

Comment: @PixelatedFish for all "*what happened to the package?*" questions, I first check `rmadison` to ensure it's really gone (often it's still there), then straight to tracker.debian.org to see if it's been abandoned.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that existed. I think you should add that to your answer as well given the number of those questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with gEDA suite, but now days we have QUCS and KiCAD.
But if you still want to install it you can use gEDA web page and download their .Deb package and install it.  Here is their web page:
http://wiki.geda-project.org/geda:download